# acts_as_shopping_cart add item routes error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cart

I'm using by the first time the gem act_as_shopping_cart, and it is not has a good documentation and I come whith the error below when I load my view item:

```
No route matches {:action=>"add_item", :id=>#<Cart id: nil, owner_id: nil, owner_type:     nil, quantity: nil, item_id: nil, item_type: nil, price: nil>, :controller=>"comprar"}
```

I'm not 100% sure how to implement this gem because the docs are not 100% clear

Here is my itens:

```
class ComprarController < SuperSiteController
  def index
    @v = Video.order('created_at asc')
    @n = News.all
    @cat = Category.all
  end

  def show
    @v = Video.find(params[:id])
    @n = News.all
    @cat = Category.all
    @cart = Cart.new
  end

  def add_item
    @cart = Cart.create
    @product = Video.find(params[:id])

    @cart.add(@product, @product.week_price)
  end

end
```

My cart model:

```
 class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :id, :owner_id, :owner_type, :quantity,
              :item_id, :item_type, :price


    acts_as_shopping_cart_using :video
  end
```

My item Model:

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :active, :desc, :embed, :img1, :img1_uid, 
            :img2, :img2_uid, :img3, :img3_uid, :img4, 
            :img4_uid, :infos, :month_price, :slug, :title, 
            :trailer, :views, :week_price, :year_price, :category_id



    belongs_to :category

  acts_as_shopping_cart_item_for :cart

end
```

and user model:

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base

       devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
        :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatabl

     end
```

And my View item function:

```
       <% form_for @cart, :url => {:action => "add_item", :id => @cart} do |f| %>
              <%= f.submit 'Add to Cart' %>
          <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your view

```
:url => {:action => "add_item", :id => @cart}
```

You are setting the `:id` to be the `@cart` object, when it should be the id of the cart object, like so:

```
:url => {:action => "add_item", :id => @cart.id}
```

Comment: Thanks man! Almost there. But now I got: No route matches {:action=>"add_item", :id=>nil, :controller=>"comprar"}